# UTL_FILE server side usage/ client side usage

Tags: oracle

I've used TEXT_IO package for creating files in the local(client) machine. From the documentation http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#BABBBABB I see that it is "available for both client-side and server-side PL/SQL". What does this mean?. Does it mean I can use it to create file in both client and server side? If so, which method/option should I use to create a file in the client side. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTL_FILE is a PL/SQL database package.  It can read from or write to any directory which the `oracle` OS account has the matching privileges on.  In practice this means directories on the database server, although directories on other servers - or even your local PC - can be shared with that server, through the good graces of your network administrator, and the DBA creating the appropriate Directory object.

TEXT_IO is an Oracle Forms package for writing to the client.  Naturally it only works in client/server versions of the product, although the webutils library provides an implementation which can work in webform deployments.

---

The `oracle` OS account is the user which installed the Oracle software.  We create the account before running the OUI.  The `oracle` user has no direct relationship to any database accounts.

Processes inside the database can only read or write files in directories which the OS account can access.  These processes include UTL_FILE, Data Pump, external tables, Java stored procedures running OS commands and extprocs, as well as background things like the alert log, dumps and trace files .

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify about "oracle OS account"?. Does oracle create an account in the OS on installation? I've noticed some users in the Oracle database having the same name as the OS username(Unix here).

Answer (score 3):

No, I think it means that UTL_FILE and TEXT_IO provide equivalent functionality for server and client respectively.